# smtp authentication virtual domain ubuntu 14.4

Tags: smtp

two domains configured as virtual domains and ubuntu 14.4 installed:

I need to configure smtp authentication for dovecot, without authentication it is working I have go through several docs but non of these are suit for my solution

regards
Kanchana

######################  refer the doveconf -n

```
root@mail:/var/log# doveconf -n
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain cram-md5
auth_verbose = yes
base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.info
log_path = /var/log/dovecot
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/auth
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
  user = dovecot
}
service imap {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
}
service pop3-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
  user = dovecot
}
service pop3 {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
valid_chroot_dirs = /var/spool/vmail
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}
```

Comment: Assume you using Postfix? Have you read through the Postfix documentation for [configuring SASL authentication](http://www.postix.org/SASL_README.html) and the related links to integrating SASL authentication with Dovecot?

Comment: yes  I try to configure it using below link (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixVirtualMailBoxClamSmtpHowto#Configure_Postfix_for_SASL )

Comment: One of the first things I noticed on that page was that it was not current for 12.04 and newer versions of Ubuntu. Can you edit your post to include the contents of `doveconf -n`? I think your problem is that Postfix and Dovecot aren't configured properly to pass off SASL authentication.

Comment: please refer the my  doveconf -n  and advice to changed it

Comment: Sorry, not sure that I understand. Open a Terminal session and run `doveconf -n`. Edit your post with the contents of the output of that command.

Comment: HI   douggro : I tried to copy and attached the doveconf -n to this forruM but I could not it asking for 10 reputation for attached the DOC

Comment: I got this error message

Comment: HI douggro Please refer the my first post  it is include the dovecont -n output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output of `doveconf -n`, Dovecot is not set to handle SMTP SASL authorizations from Postfix. You can try adding the following to your `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf` file:

```
# Add SMTP SASL authorizations from Postfix:
service auth{
unix_listener auth-userdb{
}
inet_listener {
port=12555
}
}
```

And in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, add the following:

```
# Add Dovecot listener for SASL authorizations:
smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_path=inet:127.0.0.1:12555
```

The `#` at the start of a line to add comments about the changes so you can keep track of what you changed - I recommend you do this in case you need to go back and remove the edits.

The port number `12555` is arbitrary, but make sure to use a port that is not being used for any services. Port 12555 isn't used for any common services which is why I selected it.

Restart Postfix and Dovecot with `sudo service postfix restart` and `sudo service dovecot restart`. See if this allows SMTP authorizations through Dovecot.

Comment: thanks Mr Douggro  finaly I have got through I have did below on the dovecot.conf with your help and it works thanks ##### disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth default {
  socket listen {
    client {
          path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
          mode = 0660
          user = postfix
          group = postfix
   }
 }
 mechanisms = plain cram-md5
}

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: I hope forward to get more help from you thanks any further info please post reply on this configuration

Comment: HI douggro Please check if you know below issue I am facing now  cannot ping real ip address from the LAN users,  this is ubuntu mail server with two network cards and they can send mail using only LAN interface ip as outgoing / incoming mail server IPs

but cannot send and receives mail using real IP addresess

Comment: yes the config I mentioned it works

Comment: @KanchanaNilupa If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)